# Как добавить видео на vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Делаю проект на vue, а точнее vuetify
Как сделать блок видео
типа заголовок, ниже видео, ниже текст(контент)

```html
<v-col sm="4" p-40 cols="12">
          <v-card
            class="mx-auto"
            max-width="302"
          >
            

            <v-card-subtitle class="text-left font-weight-black">Со мной актуально</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-text class="text-left">
              <div>Репортажная съемка –  всегда на пике событий.</div>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: как правильно добавить видео?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="302">
            <v-card-subtitle class="text-left font-weight-black">Со мной актуально</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-text class="text-left">
              <div>Репортажная съемка –  всегда на пике событий.</div>
              
              <video class="mx-auto col" controls>
                <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/file_example_AVI_480_750kB.avi" type="video/avi"></source>
                <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
              </video>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```